# How to increase parallelism in spark streaming to http server

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I use Spark 2.0.1 and Kafka 0.8.2. We have 6 partitions in the topic.

I have a streaming pipeline => kafka -> sparkStreaming(do some operations)-> post To Http.

For posting to http I am using java apache http client.

Below is the code

```
 processedStream.foreachRDD {
      rdd => {
        rdd.foreachPartition {
          partition => {
            val client = ClientFactory.create() // gets http client
            // grouping the data in order to avoid big data
            val groupedPartitions = partition.toList.grouped(metricPerReq.toInt).toList

            groupedPartitions.foreach(x=>postData(x,client))
            //free up client resources
            client.close()
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

But the code is taking the same time even if I increase the num of executors.
Ideally I expect some throughtput gain by increasing the number of executors.
The time taken is same when using 4 core as well as 8 cores(2mins approx) where 1 executor is 1core & 1gb   .

How to increase the parallelism ? I have tried repartition also but it is not giving performance boost.

Comment: With 6 partitions you can only have 6 executors each reading from its own partition. You know that?

Comment: Yes I am aware of that

Comment: You can have at most 6 Kafka consumers and the number of concurrent HTTP connections is the number of partitions in your KafkaRDD. Can you share an execution plan from a pipeline?

Comment: I am using directKafkaAPI and I do a reduceByKeyAndWindow before this with numOfPartitions = numOfCores*parallelfactor. This parallel factor is just to tune the number of partitions. Within each partition I am creating a http connection and using it to connect to the server.

Comment: Can you share few screenshots from web UI for a sample job?